# Largest eigenvalue of a weighted sum of two matrices

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory

Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix of an undirected and simple graph (so it is symmetric and the entries are 0 or 1).

Suppose I have a decomposition $A = B + C$ where $B$ and $C$ are matrices of same dimensions as $A$ and they also only contain 0 or 1.

My questions are

1. Can I say anything about the largest eigenvalue of a weighted sum of $B$ and $C$, say $bB + cC$ where $b$ and $c$ are constants?
2. Can I have any constraint for $b$ and $c$ so that the largest eigenvalue of $bB + cC$ less than 1?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 0):

Because $A = B + C$ is symmetric matrix, we can use several results to receive bounds on the eigenvalues of $A$ in terms of the eigenvalues of $B$ and $C$. Weyl's Inequalities state that for Hermitian matrices $B, C$ with eigenvalues ordering nondecreasingly $\lambda_1(B) \leq \lambda_2(B) \leq \cdots \leq \lambda_n(B)$ and $\lambda_1(C) \leq \lambda_2(C) \leq \cdots \leq \lambda_n(C)$, then
$$
   \lambda_i(B+C) \leq \lambda_{i+j}(B) + \lambda_{n-j}(C)
   \quad\text{for}\quad
   j = 0, 1, \ldots, n-i
$$
and
$$
    \lambda_{i-j+1}(B) + \lambda_j(C) \leq \lambda_i(B+C)
    \quad\text{for}\quad
    j = 1, \ldots, i
$$
for each $i = 1, \ldots, n$. Equality holds for a pair $i, j$ if and only if
there is a nonzero vector $\mathbf x$ such that $A \mathbf x =
\lambda_{i+j}(A) \mathbf x$ and $B \mathbf x = \lambda_j(B) \mathbf x$. If
$A$ and $B$ have no common eigenvector, then these inequalities are strict.

Scaling a matrix by a factor of $c$ scales each eigenvalue by the same factor, so the same inequalities hold for linear combinations of $B$ and $C$.
If you know more about your underlying graph it's easy to derive even stronger results. In particular, the adjacency matrices of degree-regular graphs always have the constant vector as an eigenvector, which gives them many nice properties.

Using Weyl's inequalities, it's possible to find bounds for $b$ and $c$ such that $\lambda_n(bB + cC) < 1$. If $b, c > 0$, this constraint is satisfied for
$$\begin{align*}
    \lambda_n(bB) + \lambda_n(cC) &< 1 \\
    b \lambda_n(B) + c \lambda_n(C) &< 1.
\end{align*}$$
For $b, c < 0$ the sign of each eigenvalue is reversed and $\lambda_n(bB) \neq b \lambda_n(B)$, so the above does not hold.